# DialogResult.Ok like Custom Class

Tags: c#

I am trying to develop a custom input dialog box. In its constructor I want to take a parameter as follows-

```
PromptType.Question
PromptType.Information
PromptType.Feedback
//etc....

private void buttonTest_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
   InputBoxResult result = InputBox.Show("Some title",PromptType.Question);
}
```

How can i do it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is an enum:

```
public enum PromtType
{
    Question,
    Information,
    Feedback
}

public class InputBox
{
    public static void Show(PromtType type)
    {
        //...
    }
}

InputBox.Show(PromtType.Question);
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer (ha ha ha). Please tell me how  can i catch which promptType has been selected. Sorry, this can be a foolish question, but i am not advance level coder.

Comment: @SKPaul You can either use a `switch` statement, or you can just compare the variable to one of the constants, i.e. `if(type == PromptType.Question)`.

Comment: Dear Servy, you served really great. Now all things are crystal clear to me. My vote 10 of 10.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the enum approach, and catch the selected option in a switch statement

```
public enum PromtType
{
    Question,
    Information,
    Feedback
}

public class InputBox
{
    public static void Show(PromtType type)
    {
        switch(type)
       {
           case PromtType.Question:
           //do question things here
           break;
           case PromtType.Information:
           //do information things here
           break;
           case PromtType.Feedback:
           //do feedback things here
           break;
       }
    }
}

InputBox.Show(PromtType.Question);
```

Comment: Thanks Vidal. Your example also helped me a lot.